# How come multiple AdHoc profiles keep showing up every time I add a new device?

Tags: ios, ios6

(Xcode 4.5.2)

iOS Provisioning portal just continues to freak me out.  Every time I add a device to my AdHoc profile and refresh it in the Organizer it adds another AdHoc entry instead of replacing it.  The new entry has the correct "Team" but the old ones have a "Team" of "unknown". Why are those old ones left around?

Makes this real confusing when you are in the "Code Signing" area of the project and you have a bunch of the same AdHoc profiles to choose from.

Plus, I have like 10 iOS Team provisioning profiles as well.

Whats the deal?

Answer (score 4):

Each time you add a new device to an existing profile, the profile is "rebuilt" and you download a new one from the portal.

Organizer doesn't remove the old profiles automatically, so when you import the new one, all old profiles are kept. But you can do it yourself!

Open organizer, profisioning profiles, delete all AdHoc duplicate profiles refeering to the App.
Then, you can import the new one (simply double click on the profile).

Comment: LombaX is right. Just couple of additional notes. I saw quite a lot of strange XCode behavior related to deletion, updates and so on of provision profiles. I would recommend go to Provisioning portal and clean it up manually (as example, get rid of extra Ad-Hoc profiles). After you did it, I recommend to wait for some time, I have a feeling that there is some cache, because couple of times XCode was able to get provisioning profiles, which I just deleted.